# .NET Maui Custom Thickness Based on Constants

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I would like to create custom margin/padding based on some constant values defined globally in one place. I am aware that you can define globally available Thickness objects in your App ResourceDictionary. Alternatively, you could use static constants defined in a class and reference those with x:Static.
Here is a ResourceDictionary example:

### App.xaml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:sample"
             x:Class="sample.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <Thickness x:Key="Small">5</Thickness>
                    <Thickness x:Key="Medium">10</Thickness>
                    <Thickness x:Key="Large">20</Thickness>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

It's simple enough to use these Thicknesses in my page as shown below.

### ContentPage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

     <StackLayout Margin="{x:StaticResource Small}">
        <Label Text="Hi" FontSize="Medium"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

That is great but how do I create some custom thickness based on these constant values (5,10,20 in this example) without having to list every permutation in my dictionary?
Ideally, I would like to create my custom thickness like

```
Margin="{x:StaticResource Small}, {x:StaticResource Medium}, {x:StaticResource Small}, {x:StaticResource Small}"
```

which does not work.

How do I create these constant thicknesses based on global constants? To be clear, I don't want to simply hardcode any potential permutation in the resourcedictionary. Something like

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:sample"
             x:Class="sample.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <Thickness x:Key="Small">5</Thickness>
                    <Thickness x:Key="Medium">10</Thickness>
                    <Thickness x:Key="Large">20</Thickness>

                    <Thickness x:Key="SMLL">5,10,20,20</Thickness>
                    <Thickness x:Key="LMML">20,10,10,20</Thickness>
                    <Thickness x:Key="MMML">10,10,10,20</Thickness>
                    <Thickness x:Key="MLLM">10,20,20,10</Thickness>
                    <!-- there must be a better way to do this -->
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: So do you want your thickness to change based on some other value or is it supposed to change based on device screen size or something like that?

Comment: I want to be able to create Margin/Padding with their "left, top, right, bottom" values based on some constants. The point is that any of those spacing values ("left, top, right, bottom") should be able to be set to any of the constants.

Comment: @FreakyAli I updated my question to make it more clear

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73624187/constants-for-thickness