# Constants for Thickness

Tags: xamarin.forms, .net-maui

I am looking for a way to define Thickness **in Xaml** based on application wide defined constants, e.g.

```
<StackLayout Margin="MSpace,SSpace,LSpace,MSpace">
   <Label Text="Just an example"/>
</StackLayout>
```

where SSpace, MSpace and LSpace are constants defined once in the app.

If I was only dealing with my own custom controls only I could probably write my own TypeConverter ([c# how to implement type converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43649402/c-sharp-how-to-implement-type-converter)) and decorate each property where appropriate with something like

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ConstantStringToThicknessConverter))]
```

I don't think this is an option since I want to use my string of constants with any type of Maui layout.  I am looking for a solution where everything is done in xaml with the exception of defining the constants.

Comment: Define a static class and do some binding like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360381/set-a-margin-from-a-binding)?

Comment: And found a sample here: https://github.com/tuyen-vuduc/todo-app-xamarin-forms/blob/master/src/TodoApp/UI/MarkupExtensions/EdgeInsetsExtension.cs

Comment: I feel like this shifts the problem of cluttering your code to the viewmodel. Instead of having to define a large number of static resource items now I would have to create a large number of properties.  I am looking for a solution where everything is done in xaml with the exception of defining the constants

Comment: If keep in xaml only, ResourceDictionary is the place, like how to define "boxsize" [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics#bindings-and-collections) (end of the section, or search "boxsize")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define `Thickness` in XAML `Resources`:

```
<x:Double x:Key="left">10</x:Double>
<x:Double x:Key="top">20</x:Double>
<x:Double x:Key="right">30</x:Double>
<x:Double x:Key="bottom">40</x:Double>

<Thickness x:Key="thickness" 
           Left="{StaticResource left}"
           Top="{StaticResource top}"
           Right="{StaticResource right}"
           Bottom="{StaticResource bottom}"/>
```

Usage in XAML `StackLayout`:

```
<StackLayout Margin="{StaticResource thickness}" />
```

`Thickness` can also be used like this in a `StackLayout` `Margin`:

```
<StackLayout>
  <StackLayout.Margin>
    <Thickness Left="{StaticResource left}"
               ...
  </StackLayout.Margin>
  ...
```

With constants:

```
namespace ConstantsNamespace
{
  public static class Constants
  {
    public const double Left = 10;
    ...
```

Usage of constants in XAML `Thickness`:

```
xmlns:ns="clr-namespace:ConstantsNamespace;assembly=Constants.Assembly"
...
<Thickness Left="{x:Static ns:Constants.Left}"
           ...
```

Comment: seeing that the question was tagged with `.net-maui` - in .NET Maui it seems the `Thickness` object in XAML does not have `Left`, `Right`, `Top`, `Bottom` properties. Do you have a suggestion for how to create a `Thickness` object based on constants in .NET Maui using XAML?

Comment: [`Thickness`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.thickness) in `.NET Maui` is a struct with properties `Bottom`, `Right`, `Top`, `Left`. [Intellisense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-intellisense) might not list them in auto completion.

Comment: Yes, you’re right - intellisense did not list them but when using the code anyway, it worked

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've been doing lately.

```cs
namespace MyApp.UI;

public static class UiConstants 
{
    public static readonly Thickness DefaultMargin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10);
}
```

```xml
<ContentPage ...
    xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:MyApp.UI">
    <StackLayout Margin="{x:Static ui:UiConstants.DefaultMargin}">
        <Label Text="Just an example"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Hi Michal, I appreciate the suggestion. This is the solution I am currently using but I am not very happy with it. The problem with this approach is that I would have to define any possible combination of constants I would need in UiConstants. This becomes soon pretty messy and I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: Oh, I see. I don't have a solution for that, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this function by using c# .

please refer to the following code:

1.create class `Constants.cs`

```
public  class Constants 
{

    public static readonly int MSpace = 20;
    public static readonly int SSpace = 20;
    public static readonly int LSpace = 20;
}
```

2.A simple usage :

```
   public class TestPage1 : ContentPage 
{

    Thickness thickness = new Thickness (Constants.MSpace, Constants.SSpace, Constants.LSpace, Constants.MSpace);

    public TestPage1()
    {
        Content = new StackLayout
        { 
            BackgroundColor= Color.Yellow,

            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" ,Margin= thickness }
                
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**Update:**

> can I do the same thing in xaml?

You can bind the defined `thickness`  to your control as a whole in your xaml.

Please refer to the following code:

```
public  class Constants 
{

    public static readonly int MSpace = 50;
    public static readonly int SSpace = 50;
    public static readonly int LSpace = 50;


    public Thickness thickness
    {
        get
        {
            return new Thickness(Constants.MSpace, Constants.SSpace, Constants.LSpace, Constants.MSpace);
        }
    }
}
```

And a simple usage :

```
   <ContentPage.BindingContext> 
        <formapp908:Constants></formapp908:Constants>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>

            <BoxView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="100"></BoxView>

            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"   Margin="{ Binding  thickness}" BackgroundColor="Green" HeightRequest="80"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Jessie, very true but can I do the same thing in xaml?

Comment: You can check my updated answer at the bottom of my reply.

Comment: I feel like this shifts the problem of cluttering your code to the viewmodel. Instead of having to define a large number of static resource items now I would have to create a large number of properties.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using styles without keys?

In your App.xaml.cs

```
    const double MSpace = 30;
    const double SSpace= 30;
    const double LSpace= 30;

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // You can replace this with a constant file if you want too
        Application.Current.Resources.Add("MSpace", MSpace);
        Application.Current.Resources.Add("SSpace", SSpace);
        Application.Current.Resources.Add("LSpace", LSpace);
        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
```

Then in your App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="StackLayout">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{DynamicResource MSpace, SSpace, LSpace}" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then wherever in your app

```
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Just an example" />
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I will need to have different stacklayouts with different margin thicknesses in my app. Setting it once globally for all stacklayouts will not work in my scenario

Comment: @MouseOnMars then you can set keys on your App.xaml